# What is the Laurent series of function $f(z)= 1 / (1- z ^2)$ with centre at $z=1$?

Tags: laurent-series

What will be the Laurent series for above function?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange.  To get help here, please [edit] the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Set $z=1+u$. This function can be rewritten as

$$\frac{1}{1-z^2}=\frac 1{(1-z)(1+z)}=-\frac1{2u}\,\frac1{1+\cfrac u2}$$
and you can expand the second fraction with the geometric series.